# Python dataframes - How to apply threads/multiprocessing here to speed up things

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with millions of rows and I have to perform a function on `col_1` and `col_2` of each row.
See the example below. Suppose each function takes 2 seconds and I have 3 rows, so currently it takes 6 seconds. I want to use threads here, to reduce the time to 2 seconds. What should I do?

```
import pandas as pd
import time

def add(a,b):
    sum = a+b
    time.sleep(2) #just to show that in reality my function takes times
    print("sum of %d and %d is %d" %(a, b, sum))

data = [[10,10],[9,12],[100,13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col_1','col_2'])

start_time = time.time()
df.apply(lambda x: add(x.col_1, x.col_2), axis=1)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ltpitt/6cdcb5377c462445a315703c5062397c

Comment: Are you sure there can't be a pandas solution for your problem, that you have to write a function to work on each row? Why don't you post a question with what you want to achieve in your function, and maybe someone would find a better solution than writing a function to use with `apply`.

Comment: `.apply` just hides a for-loop, and iteration is very very slow.  Many pandas operations are natively multiprocessed in the C library.  Your best bet is to find a way to use the pandas API to do as much of the calculation as possible.

Comment: my function is very very complex, input are api endpoints and functions involve api requests, doing some actions, some assertions and lot of thing.

Comment: @SaurabhShrivastava, in that case your function does file I/O, network I/O - yes I would apply whether threading or async approach

Answer (score 1):

ok, thanks everyone. Async approach worked.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

pool_size = 5

pool = Pool(pool_size)


def add(a,b):
    sum = a+b
    time.sleep(2) #just to show that in reality my function takes times
    print("sum of %d and %d is %d" %(a, b, sum))

data = [[10,10],[9,12],[100,13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col_1','col_2'])

start_time = time.time()
for ind in df.index:
     pool.apply_async(add, args=(df['col_1'][ind], df['col_2'][ind],))
pool.close()
pool.join()



print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```